# Libgdx ExtendViewport not working properly with Scene2D UI

Tags: java, libgdx, scene2d

I need to use the Extendview port in my game it works fine without a scene2d but when I add scene2d I get a big bar at the top instead of 2 bars at the top and bottom.

Here is the full code:

```
public class MenuScreen extends ScreenAdapter {
    private SpinBlaster game;
    private OrthographicCamera camera;
    private Viewport viewport;
    private Stage stage;
    private Sprite backgroundSprite = new Sprite();

    public MenuScreen(SpinBlaster game) {
        this.game = game;
    }

    public void show() {
        camera = new OrthographicCamera();
        camera.position.set(Constants.CENTER_X, Constants.CENTER_Y, 0);
        viewport = new ExtendViewport(Constants.VIRTUAL_W, Constants.VIRTUAL_H, camera);

        stage = new Stage(viewport);
        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);
    }

    public void render(float delta) {
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0,1,0, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        game.batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
        game.batch.begin();
        backgroundSprite.setRegion(AssetLoader.atlas.findRegion("background"));
        backgroundSprite.setPosition(0,0);
        backgroundSprite.setSize(Constants.VIRTUAL_W, Constants.VIRTUAL_H);
        backgroundSprite.setColor(Constants.DARK_GRAY);
        backgroundSprite.draw(game.batch);
        game.batch.end();

        stage.draw();
        stage.act(delta);
    }

    public void resize(int width, int height) {
        viewport.update(width, height);
        camera.update();
    }
```

[image].

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by setting the camera position below the `viewport.update`

```
public void resize(int width, int height) {
        viewport.update(width, height);
        camera.position.set(Constants.CENTER_X, Constants.CENTER_Y, 0); // fixed
        camera.update();
}
```